# Difficulty with this sentence

Tags: translation

「こうして、あなたのことを奪い取って、
でも、さくらが逃げ出すのも許さずに、
一生、地獄を見せるつもりなのかも…」

In this sentence X is talking to Y and Sakura is the third person.

My question: who is going to suffer? Sakura or Y?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that Sakura ran away and therefor shall not be forgiven and there will be hell to pay for that!.

さくらが逃げ出す

> Sakura run away

許さずに

> Without forgiving

地獄

> Hell

見せるつもり

> Plan to show

Y also seems to get robbed though.

Comment: And who will suffer the consequences?

Comment: "一生、地獄を見せるつもりなのかも" to whom does it refer to?

Comment: @TheBeast I feel like both are possible without more context, but I would tend to say maybe Sakura because つもり was used. So it feels like "when I get him I will make him pay". It could also mean that I will make you pay for him running away but in that case one would usually use "逃がす" for "let get away ".

Comment: I'm going to give you more context to make sure. This is what happens: X is a girl and Y a boy. Both X and Sakura are in love with the boy. X steals the boy (marries him). X also talks about revenge and hating Y, but doesn't want Y to leave them. With all that, you think it is Sakura that will suffer?

Comment: @TheBeast Revenge for what? Why angry at Y? Why sakura was running away an unforgivable thing? Shouldn't it be a good thing if she want him all for herself? Is it X fault that sakura ran away? If not, I don't see why Y would be unforgivable.

Comment: More context: both girls are best friends. X is angry at Y because she tried to get him as well. X wants to hog the boy but doesn't want to lose her best (and only) friend. The boy asks X to marry him knowing that Sakura is likely going to run away because of that. In the past Sakura ran away because her best friend took the boy she loved. Now all 3 of them are friends again and X fears that by marrying the boy the same may happen yet again. Now that you know that, what are your thoughts? The last sentence, to whom does it refer to? Could you translate the whole text? (to erase my doubts)

Comment: 「さくらが逃げ出すのも許さずに」は、"won't let Sakura run away" 「さくらを逃がさずに」「さくらを捕まえておきながら」ってことです

Comment: @TheBeast Wow, ok, getting more and more confused haha. It seems that sakura didn't run away yet(in the present) so 許さずに might be interpreted as to "not allow". So the whole thing might mean : "I take you, and don't allow her to run/leave our trio, her life will become hell by seeing us together every day of her life".. maybe.

Comment: 「あなたに地獄を見せる」のか「さくらに地獄を見せる」のか、はっきりとはわかんないですね・・さくらかな？って感じはしますけど・・

Comment: @Shoko やっぱりそうだね。最初から読まないとな。

Comment: @stack So is that your final version? It is Sakura who will suffer? Can you also tell me Shoko's opinion? (in english).

Comment: @TheBeast Shoko said that it is very hard to know which one. Could be either. But he has a small gut feeling that it might be Sakura.